# Неправильная проверка regex каждый второй раз

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

#### Описание

Есть массив строк и одно условие regex. Просто проходя по этим строкам циклично проверяю их с помощью `RegExp.test()`:

```js
const regex = new RegExp(`A`, `gmi`);
const examples = [
  `A-3-1`,
  `A-3-1`,
  `A-3-1`,
  `A-3-1`,
  `A-3-1`,
  `A-3-1`,
  `A-3-1`,
  `A-3-1`,
];
for (let index = 0; index < examples.length; index++) {
  const example = examples[index];
  console.log(`${example} -> ${regex.test(example)}`);
}
```

Специально взял и поставил **8 одинаковых строк в массиве**.

#### Вопрос

Почему **каждая вторая проверка возвращает `false`**, если строки одинаковые и условие тот же.

Comment: строки одинаковые, а регулярки разные. Один раз "А", а другой "gmi", потом опять "A". Или другая причина, но если убрать "gmi", то правильно отрабатывает.

Comment: @Эникейщик, но ведь у RegExp [перегрузка](https://imgur.com/RjoijGv.png) принимает 2 аргумента - условие и флаги

Comment: второй - опциональный. Это флаги, оказывается, я не знал. Странно, эти флаги не должны влиять. Но в любом случае, если второй аргумент убрать, то все работает.

Comment: В общем, влияет флаг "g". Если его убрать, то все работает. А если оставить только его, то тоже через раз получается.

Comment: Ну как бы в этом и смысл флага `g`. А зачем вы его написали?

Comment: @AlexeyTen читал когда-то что флаг `g` помогает `matchAll()` найти все соответствия. Изначально в проекте использовал `matchAll` с `g` флагом, потом переписал часть кода и оставил его, так как не знал что он на что-то ещё влияет.

Comment: `g` - global, нужен для получения всех совпадающих строк, пример: `'   '.replace(new RegExp('\\s'), '')` - уберёт один пробел, а `'   '.replace(new RegExp('\\s', 'g'), '')` уберёт все пробелы. (`new RegExp('\\s', 'g') = /\s/g`)

Comment: @AlexeyTen Чуть подробнее можно ознакомиться [на MDN](//developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/global)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Одно и то же регулярное выражение, использованное повторно на другом тексте, может дать другой результат

Если мы применяем одно и то же регулярное выражение последовательно к разным строкам, это может привести к неверному результату, поскольку вызов `regexp.test` обновляет свойство `regexp.lastIndex`, поэтому поиск в новой строке может начаться с ненулевой позиции.

Например, здесь мы дважды вызываем `regexp.test` для одного и того же текста, и второй раз поиск завершается уже неудачно:

```
let regexp = /javascript/g;  // (regexp только что создан: regexp.lastIndex=0)

alert( regexp.test("javascript") ); // true (теперь regexp.lastIndex=10)
alert( regexp.test("javascript") ); // false
```

> Это именно потому, что во втором тесте regexp.lastIndex не равен нулю.

Чтобы обойти это, можно присвоить `regexp.lastIndex = 0` перед новым поиском.

```js
const regex = new RegExp(`A`, 'gmi');
const examples = [
  `A-3-1`,
  `A-3-1`,
  `A-3-1`,
  `A-3-1`,
  `A-3-1`,
  `A-3-1`,
  `A-3-1`,
  `A-3-1`,
];
for (let index = 0; index < examples.length; index++) {
  const example = examples[index];
  regex.lastIndex = 0;
  console.log(regex.test(example));
}
```

Из документации по [regexp-methods](https://learn.javascript.ru/regexp-methods)

Comment: Также об этом было упомянуто [в MDN](//developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0_%D1%81_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8). (После таблицы с надписью `Table 4.3 Результаты выполнения регулярного выражения`)