# Регулярное выражение?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

Подскажите пожалуйста регулярное выражение. Нужно чтобы в строке обязательно было # и не меньше и не больше 4 цифр. Вот так: test#1111, вот это не правильно: test#11111

Вот моя регулярка, оно работает, но когда у меня 5 цифр, то оно все равно возвращает true
Вот это работает: `/#\d{4}/g.test('test#33443')`

Comment: А чего не может быть после этих 4-х цифр? Строка же любая может быть, например `test#1234 5` - она приемлима?

Comment: И ещё вопрос: строка `a1b2c3d4` валидна или нет? В строке ровно 4 цифры, но не подряд

Answer (score 2):

Используйте [утверждения](https://efim360.ru/ecmascript-utverzhdenie-assertion-regulyarnye-vyrazheniya-regular-expression/). Дополните выражение тем что после четвертой цифры не должно быть пятого.

```js
const regex = /#\d{4}(?!\d)/;
[`test#4444`, `test#55555`].forEach(text => {
  console.log(`${text} → ${regex.test(text)}`);
});
```

---

#### Момент

Осторожно с флагом `g`. Повторное использование одного выражения с флагом `g` может резко менять результат:

```js
const regex = /#\d{4}(?!\d)/g;
[`test#1234`, `test#2341`, `test#3412`, `test#4123`].forEach(text => {
  console.log(`${text} → ${regex.test(text)}`);
});
```

Почему так происходит, ответили [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1475768/324730).

Comment: `Осторожно с флагом g.` - Это из-за пропорции `lastIndex`, её нужно при каждом использовании  выражения с флагом `g` приводить к нулю, тогда всё заработает. Правда ли это, можно проверить так: (Способ первый) на каждой итерации у `regex` пропорцию `lastIndex` приводить к нулю. (Способ второй) Вместо объявления `regex` вне функции (которая передана аргументом в `forEach`), объявляйте `regex` в самой функции.

Comment: @ΝNL993 я знаю зачем это происходит. Просто краткое предупреждение о том, чтобы не использовать этот флаг там, где он не обязателен.

Comment: Лучше бы и автору это объяснить раз уже упомянули это или хотя бы дать ссылку на доки, где этот момент обговаривается

Comment: @EzioMercer добавил.

Comment: А, вы вопрос решили найти :) Я бы дал ссылку на [доки](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex) :)

Comment: @EzioMercer вопрос просто мой, где я ясно объяснил проблему и мне так же ясно и с примером дали хороший ответ. Считаю что он лучше документации :)

Comment: Ваше право :)))

Answer (score 1):

Про регулярные выражения важно понять одну вещь: если паттерну соответствует любая часть строки, совпадение засчитывается.

Поэтому паттерн `/123/` будет соответствовать любой строке, где есть цифры 1, 2 и 3 — в начале, середине или конце: `123abc`, `123`, `12345`, `01234`, `-123`.

Поэтому важно задавать ограничения. Чаще всего паттерну должен удовлетворять текст в начале строки, тогда в начале паттерна ставят "крышку" `^`.

`/^123/` будет соответствовать любой строке, которая *начинается* с 123.

Точно также `/123$/` будет соответствовать любой строке, которая заканчивается на 123.

Если бы вы хотели, чтобы строка состояла из `#` и четырёх цифр, вам подошёл бы паттерн `/^#\d\d\d\d$/` или `/^#\d{4}$/`. `^` в начале и `$` в конце указывают, что строка должна соответствовать паттерну целиком.

Но в вашем случае ограничения должны быть более тонкими. Паттерну должна удовлетворять часть строки, но есть дополнительное условие: сразу за ним не должно быть цифры. У нас по сути получается два паттерна. Сначала мы находим часть строки, которая соответствует первому паттерну, а потом заглядываем вперёд (look ahead) и убеждаемся, что оставшаяся часть строки соответствует второму.

Второй паттерн надо указать сразу после первого в скобках `(?=)` или `(?!)`.

`/#\d{4}(?!\d)/` означает "после проверки паттерна `#\d{4}` заглянуть дальше и убедиться, что там **не цифра**". Это — *негативная* проверка.

`(?=)` это *позитивная* проверка, то есть мы убеждается, что за первым паттерном точно следует второй. Утверждение **не цифра** мы можем выразить и так, но выражение будет сложнее `/#\d{4}(?=[^\d])/`. Мы помним, что `[^\d]` соответствует любому символу, который не является цифрой.

Comment: Самый лучший и подробный ответ. Побольше бы таких, а не просто куски кода кидать...

Answer (score 0):

> Нужно чтобы в строке обязательно было # и не меньше и не больше 4 цифр. Вот так: test#1111, вот это не правильно: test#11111

Предложу такой вариант...

```js
console.log(/#\d{4}(?=[^\d]|$)/g.test('test#33443'))
console.log(/#\d{4}(?=[^\d]|$)/g.test('test#3344'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Предложу свой вариант без [lookahead assertion и negative lookahead assertion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Assertions#other_assertions)

Регулярка:

1. `#` - искомая строка должна начинаться с этого знака
2. `\d` - любая цифра. `\d{4}` - подряд 4 цифры
3. `[^\d]` - любой символ кроме цифры
4. `$` - конец строки
5. `|` - оператор или. `[^\d]|$` - или не цифра или конец строки

```js
const regex = /#\d{4}([^\d]|$)/;

[
  'test#123',
  'test#1234',
  'test#12345',
  'test#1234 5',
  'test#1234end',
].forEach(text => console.log(text, regex.test(text)));
```

По постановке задачи, не вижу смысла использовать `lookahead assertion` или `negative lookahead assertion` т.к. допустимым символом после 4-х цифр - это просто либо не цифра либо же конец строки